# Can I use document.getElementById() before the DOM is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if it is correct to use `document.getElementById()` before the DOM is fully loaded.

I mean, **under** the definition of the DOM element.

**Example**:

```
<html>
<head>...
<body>
<div id="hello">...
...
<script>
document.getElementById('hello')...
</script>
...
```

I tried it and it works, but I want to know if it's okay to do so.

I am aware that I can listen to the DOM load event and act depending on it, but I don't want to do that if it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: "but I don't want to do that if it's not strictly necessary"... Why not? Even if it's not "strictly necessary", it's better than having to be the guy who inherits your code and has to figure out why he can't move an element to somewhere else in the DOM. Also, every time you add a `<script>` element, the browser switches from the HTML parser to the script parser, slowing down the loading of the screen.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This is indeed very useful information. I thank you a lot for it and will proceed with the more correct way then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to do that. Scripts are often placed at the end of the `<body>` tag, so you don't have to wait for the DOM load event.

Comment: "perfectly fine"? Placing the script at the end of the `body` is one thing, since you know all other HTML elements have been parsed and loaded in the DOM, but adding script just below the element it acts on? I'd hardly call that "perfectly fine".

Comment: Why do you think it would be a problem?

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it answers the original question. I am now aware that this is not the best way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to do this way:

```
<html>
<head>...
<body>
<div id="hello"> 
...

<script>
 const myHello  = document.getElementById('hello');

myHello.onclick=evt=>
  {
...
  }

</script></body></html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But thanks for your intention.

Comment: @AlvaroFranz I mean the script must be unique and the last part of the body. I mean that element of the body must be put in constants to be used next, and not directly as you imply in your extract